# Map projection and localization in long distance operation

Tags: coordinate-system

I work in the field of robotics.

When the ground robot was moving over long distances, we faced the
problem of increasing distortions when using UTM projection relative to the central meridian of the zone in localization and mapping tasks. The use of a private transverse Mercator projection also does not work at significant distances of movement.

This leads to the need to stop and reinitialize the system with setting new datum value.

Are there standard approaches to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the dimension of the log distances?

Comment: 700 km, but I want to solve the problem in general case

Comment: There is no global projection which is accurate for distance. If you want a generic solution for distance and bearing on a spheroid you need to use a geodetic library (which will calculate both distance/bearing from two points and a second point from point/distance/bearing)

Comment: yes, I understand this. the problem is reduced not only to calculating the distance between two points and orientation.

The main problem is that the algorithmic blocks, that make up the control system, live in rectangular coordinates. They buffer data from previous iterations for their subsequent work.

One of the solutions is seen in the estimation of distortions, the choice of a new datum point, the synchronization algorithm for the simultaneous switching of all system blocks and wrapping over the
buffered data for their recalculation at the moment of switching.